# How to proced further in Putty to get details from parse server

Tags: parsing, parse-platform, bitnami

I am trying to access parse through Putty.....I have successfully opened the Bitnami screen but after that, if I try to type cd apps/parse/htdocs to get the Masterkey and app id it says that no such directory exists. Please help me how can I solve this. please see the screenshot below. I do not know how I should proceed further to get all the details from parse server

[image]

edited : I got this picture now but this is not the real details.

[image]

Comment: Bitnami Engineer here. The Bitnami Parse files are inside the /opt/bitnami/parse and /opt/bitnami/parse-dashboard folders. If you are looking for the configuration file of Parse, you will find a config.json file at /opt/bitnami/parse/config.json. I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for answering me. I followed your steps and its telling me "permission denied".

Comment: In that case, use `sudo` to edit the file. `sudo vim /opt/bitnami/parse/config.json`.

Comment: This is possible that my appId is : myappID ?  Its gave me masterKey